# ASP .Net Core 3.1 Angular template doesn't work

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

[image]I create a new Web Project .Net Core with Angular template in Visual Studio 2019.
When I try to build solution I have a error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: ))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)

InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger).

Comment: Something failed when trying to start the angular part of your app. I'd try to start the angular app outside of visual studio (command line) hoping to get more error details there. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#run-ng-serve-independently

Comment: Maybe the `npm install` failed and not all the needed thirdparties are downloaded properly. Could you please navigate in console into the `ClientApp` folder and call `npm install`? What is the output of the install? Is there any error while installation?

Comment: I try npm install and also I run the app from console line, but still give me the same error

Comment: If you try to run only the Angular app from command line, do you get any errors? To start only the Angular app from command line navigate into the `ClientApp` folder and run `npm run start`.

Comment: I can run just Angular app, but I can't run the whole project.

Comment: When I run inside Client App ng serve is working .
But when I try to run from Visual studio iis gives me the same error.Also when I try to run dotnet run from command line

Comment: The problem should be related with adding spa services to asp.net application, probably about dist directory path. Can you check your dist folder configuration?

Comment: I try to build the app with default configurations.
I don't change anything yet.

Comment: Could you please try to replace in the `Startup.cs` file the `spa.UseAngularCliServer(..)` invocation to `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");`. After this try `npm run start` command line command from the `ClientApp` folder and after that start the .NET Core application from Visual Studio or from the command line using `dotnet run`.

Comment: Thank you @tenkmilan.
This solve my problem.

Comment: @Gjurgica: You are welcome, I posted the conclusion as answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in the comments of the question turned out the default configuration in the request-response pipeline (in the `Startup.cs`) with `spa.UseAngularCliServer(..)` invocation did not work.

Changing the `spa.UseAngularCliServer(..)` invocation to `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");` solved the issue. This way the Angular application has to be started separately from the root of the `ClientApp` folder using `npm run start` command-line command.

Further details about using `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` [can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#run-ng-serve-independently).